# short and friendly URL for affiliate links

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, links

This is my first question here on Pro Webmaster... I'm really glad to be here!

I believe this question will have a simple answer but I'm starting with htaccess and I want to learn something about this file and its rules.

I have a long and ugly affiliate link but I want to create a 301 redirect to this URL, without typing it. My website is http://www.matthewlabs.com/ and I want to use a link like http://www.matthewlabs.com/wishonlist/appstore which automatically redirects to my affiliate link.

I tried to write this in my htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /wishonlist/appstore http://myAffiliateLinkHere
```

but it doesn't work. Must the directory /wishonlist/appstore exist to redirect? Because now I receive a 404 error...
And to use this link, can I create a simple link with html a tag?

```
<a href="http://www.matthewlabs.com/wishonlist/appstore">Click</a>
```

Thank you so much for your time and I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **.htaccess** file needs to look something like this:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule [URL to redirect from] [URL to redirect to] [options]

**RewriteEngine on** basically switches the mod_rewrite module on.

Then you need to say what the URL you're expecting people to enter looks like, you can use regular expressions here, in fact, the whole thing IS a regular expression.

URL to redirect to is usually internal, but it should work with a full link.

So in practice, something like:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^/wishonlist/appstore(/)?$ http://myAffiliateLinkHere [301,L]

The **^** and **$** to denote the start and end of the URL, and **(/)?** means that it can be entered with or without a trailing slash and still work.

Options - The 301 basically says send a 301 header, and L says this is a 'last instruction' - after which no more instructions should be processed.

There's a good wealth of options available, check the documentation - but here's a link to a good cheat sheet I always keep handy: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... I tried it but without success... This is my htaccess file: http://cl.ly/Chba Now I get an Internal Server Error

Comment: I would try redirecting to a simpler, short URL on the same machine first, see if that works.  If so, then try a short, simple URL on another host, and if so, build up your URL till you find whats causing the problem.  Two guesses - one, the space between '301' and 'L', or more likely, some character(s) in the long URL that need to be escaped (with a backslash).